# Xiaomi. Unable to allow app run in background [solved]

Tags: xiaomi

I accidently disabled **play market** run in background. As result when display is turning off play market stop upgrade apps in background. I'm trying to enable again. But there no **play market** in list.

## Upd 1.

Yes, it's Google play store. I has another locale and trying to translate in English all names :)

I followed next way:

Permissions / Other Permissions / *There no play store here*

Here are screenshots:

[image][image] [image]

## Upd 2.

Two more screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: By play market you mean Google play store? Or another market?

Comment: in what list? add a screenshot if it helps to describe what you're seeing

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: One more update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try **uninstalling** Google play store and then re-install it (you can also side-load it).

Sometimes this application comes as a system-core application and thus can't easily be uninstalled and the only option is **unistalling the updates**. In that scenario go for the latter option.

---

<sup>(This workaround is what solved the OP's problem )</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your response, but nothing helped me. Let's walk through all points. 1) don't have dev options at all. 2) the only advice which logically could help. However my phone is ignoring it, or the issue is referring to sth else. 3) don't have such notify option. And how it can help​? 4) locked app, but also didn't help. 5) as I can see, it's the same as 2. 6) also dunno how it can refer to my issue. Anyway thanks for spent time on writing post

Comment: Sorry couldn't help resolve this issue, but how about unistalling Google playstore, then sideload it again?

Comment: Looks like my current OS doesn't allow me to do that. Maybe I don't know how to do that, but inside settings if I choose Play Store there is the only option to remove all updates. **I tried to do that and it helped me! Magic, no less...** Please update your post with suggesting to remove (and maybe as an option, remove updates), from my side I flag it as accepted.

Comment: Phew that's great!,  I updated post :)